# Proguard/R8 exception to a keep rule

Tags: android, exception, logging, proguard, android-r8

I am trying to remove logging using R8/Proguard, and I used

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    v(...);
    d(...);
    i(...);
    w(...);
    e(...);
}
```

which works fine. The issue arrised when trying to remove the custom logging in `com.mypackage`:

```
-assumenosideeffects class com.mypackage.MyCustomLogger {
    v(...);
    d(...);
    i(...);
    w(...);
    e(...);
}
```

I have a rule that keeps all the public methods of the public classes from `com.mypackage`:

```
-keep, allowoptimization public class com.mypackage.** {
    public *;
}
```

which I can't remove due to the scope of the project. This rule seemingly overrides the `assumenosideeffects` rule, and here is my question: **how do I specify an exception to this keep rule?** I know about the `-if` option but I haven't seen it anywhere used in the negative. I've tried writing `-if class !com.mypackage.Logger` before the `-keep` rule, but the build is taking a ridiculous amount of time and just never finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer, I need to add my Logger class within the keep rule like so:

```
-keep, allowoptimization public class !com.mypackage.MyCustomLogger, com.mypackage.** {
    public *;
}
```